# Strange object assignment behaviour c++

Tags: c++, class, constructor, visual-studio-2017, destructor

I have a strange behavior with object assignments. I will much appreciate, if you can explain why this assignment works like this. It has cost me already a lot of time.
I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 (all default settings).

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:

    Test()
    {
        cout << "Constructor of " << this << endl;
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        cout << "Destructor of " << this << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    cout << "Assignment 1" << endl;
    auto t = Test();
    cout << "Assignment 2" << endl;
    t = Test();

    int i = 0;
    cin >> i;
    return 0;
}
```

Output (up to cin):

```
Assignment 1
Constructor of 006FFC9F
Assignment 2
Constructor of 006FFBC7
Destructor of 006FFBC7
```

Expected Output (up to cin):

```
Assignment 1
Constructor of 006FFC9F
Assignment 2
Destructor of 006FFC9F
Constructor of 006FFBC7
```

I wanted to write a test function which creates an object of my (template) class, do some tests, then create a new object and do some more testing. The problem is that t holds the already destructed object after the second assignment.
I know that I can just use dynamic allocation which results in the expected behavior, but why does this program behave different?

Thank you very much.
Regards.

PS: Results are the same, independent of Release/Debug or 64/32 bit compilation

EDIT: **More verbose example:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
    float* val;
public:
    Test()
    {
        val = new float;
        cout << "Constructor of " << this << ", addr. of val: " << val << endl;
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        cout << "Destructor of " << this << ", addr. of val: " << val << " --> DELETING VAL!" << endl;
        delete val;
    }

    float* getVal() { return this->val; }
};


int main()
{
    cout << "Assignment 1" << endl;
    auto t = Test();
    cout << "Assignment 2" << endl;
    t = Test();
    cout << "Val Address: " << t.getVal() << endl;

    int i = 0;
    cin >> i;
    return 0;
}
```

Output (it holds a deleted pointer at the end!!!):

```
Assignment 1
Constructor of 004FFBDC, addr. of val: 0072AEB0
Assignment 2
Constructor of 004FFB04, addr. of val: 00723928
Destructor of 004FFB04, addr. of val: 00723928 --> DELETING VAL!
Val Address: 00723928
```

Comment: Have a look at copy ellision, which is must be performed in certain cases since C++17.

Comment: `auto t = Test();` is not an assignment, but an initialization.

Comment: In `t = Test();` You construct a temporary object of `Test`, pass it to `operator=` of `t`, and then, destroy such temporary. Why do you think, it is a problem? If you put print statement in `operator=` (and, maybe, copy-constructor, for the sake of completeness), you would see this behavior, clearly.

Comment: "*t holds the already destructed object after the second assignment*" No, it doesn't It holds the newly constructed object which has replaced the object that was no longer needed. At no time does your code require two `Test` objects to exist at the same time.

Comment: The lifetime of local variables is until the end of the code block they are declared in. So you should not expect to see `t`'s destructor called until you reach the `}` at the end of `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion seems to be a mistaken expectation that the original object is destroyed when assignment takes place. Like, in this code:

```
cout << "Assignment 2" << endl;
t = Test();
```

This piece of code invokes the move-assign operator. Since you didn't define one, the default one generated by the compiler is more-or-less going to look like this:

```
Test & operator=(Test &&) {}
```

Note how there's no invocation of a constructor or (critically) a destructor in that code. The only Constructors and Destructors that are going to run are on the temporary object (which is what you observe in the actual output). The original object doesn't get destroyed until the code goes out of scope; and why would it? It's not like you can stop using the stack space before then.

Edit: Something which might help you understand what's going on:

```
#include<iostream>

struct Test {
    Test() {std::cout << "Constructed.\n";}
    ~Test() {std::cout << "Destructed.\n";}
    Test(Test const&) {std::cout << "Copy-Constructed.\n";}
    Test(Test &&) {std::cout << "Move-Constructed.\n";}
    Test & operator=(Test const&) {std::cout << "Copy-Assigned.\n"; return *this;}
    Test & operator=(Test &&) {std::cout << "Move-Assigned.\n"; return *this;}
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Test t;\n";
    Test t; //Construction
    std::cout << "Test t2(t);\n";
    Test t2(t); //Copy-Construct
    std::cout << "Test t3(std::move(t2));\n";
    Test t3(std::move(t2)); //Move-Construct
    std::cout << "Test t4 = t;\n";
    Test t4 = t; //Copy Construct, due to Copy Ellision
    std::cout << "Test t5 = Test();\n";
    Test t5 = Test(); //Will probably be a normal Construct, due to Copy Ellision
    std::cout << "t = t2;\n";
    t = t2; //Copy Assign
    std::cout << "t = Test();\n";
    t = Test(); //Move Assign, will invoke Constructor and Destructor on temporary
    std::cout << "Done! Cleanup will now happen!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Results as seen when [compiled here](http://ideone.com/uJ1nmy):

```
Test t;
Constructed.
Test t2(t);
Copy-Constructed.
Test t3(std::move(t2));
Move-Constructed.
Test t4 = t;
Copy-Constructed.
Test t5 = Test();
Constructed.
t = t2;
Copy-Assigned.
t = Test();
Constructed.
Move-Assigned.
Destructed.
Done! Cleanup will now happen!
Destructed.
Destructed.
Destructed.
Destructed.
Destructed.
```

**DOUBLE EDIT COMBO!**:

As I mentioned in comments, `val` is just a pointer. 8 bytes (on a 64-bit machine) allocated as part of `Test`'s storage. If you're trying to make sure that `Test` always contains a valid value for `val` that hasn't been deleted, you need to implement the [Rule of Five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) (previously known as the Rule of Three):

```
class Test {
    float * val;
public:
    Test() {val = new float;}
    ~Test() {delete val;
    Test(Test const& t) {
        val = new float(*(t.val));
    }
    Test(Test && t) {std::swap(val, t.val);}
    Test & operator=(Test const& t) {
        float * temp = new float(*(t.val)); //Gives Strong Exception Guarantee
        delete val; 
        val = temp;
        return *this;
    }
    Test & operator=(Test && t) {std::swap(val, t.val); return *this;};

    float & get_val() const {return *val;} //Return by reference, not by pointer, to 
        //prevent accidental deletion.
};
```

Comment: I added a more verbose example with a float pointer. The pointer gets deleted and the value is still assigned to the object?!

Comment: @Fhnx Follow the edit I just made to see what's going on. Also, FYI, `delete`ing a pointer doesn't clear the value of the pointer itself, it only deletes the memory that it's pointing to. `float *` is 8 bytes allocated on the stack, pointing to a segment of 4 bytes which is allocated with `new` and destructed with `delete`. Whether `val` is pointing to valid memory, has been destroyed, or whatever, nothing is stopping you from printing out the value of `val` or reassigning it.

Comment: Thank you for your verbose example. This and the response from @Some other programmer dude explains my mistake. So I should be fine with an additional copy-constructor.

Answer (score 3):

With

```
auto t = Test();
```

you actually construct *two* objects. First is the `Test()` which constructs a temporary object. The second is the construction of `t` which is made through *copy-construction*. There is no assignment being made here, even if the `=` operator is used, it's copy-construction.

If you add a copy-constructor to the `Test` class similar to your constructor and destructor, you should see it clearly.

---

As for

```
t = Test();
```

here a *temporary* object is created with `Test()`. That temporary object is then passed to the (compiler-generated) assignment operator of the `Test` class, and then the temporary object is promptly destructed.

The object `t` itself is not destructed, it should not be as it is the destination of the assignment.

Comment: Might not see the copy since it can be elided.

Comment: I think the confusion is with the second assignment, not the first.

Comment: With the added copy constructor: 

 Test(const Test& obj) {
  cout << "Copy-Constr of " << this << endl;
 }

My Output stays the same:
Assignment 1
Constructor of 009BFEBF
Assignment 2
Constructor of 009BFDE7
Destructor of 009BFDE7

Comment: And with your behavior the lines with "Assignment X" are at the wrong places. And It does not explain, why the first object doesn't get destroyed, but the second (and no object else).

Comment: @Fhnx _And It does not explain, why the first object doesn't get destroyed_ Why does it need to be destroyed? It's assignment operator gets called (auto-generated, in this case), which, transfers the state of the temporary `Test`, to the object `t`.

Comment: I added a more verbose example with a float pointer. Can you explain this behavior? That was the exact point where started scratching my head.

Comment: @Fhnx Ouch! Without [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) that pointer will lead to *undefined behavior*. When the compiler-generated copy-constructor or assignment-operator is called, it will copy *the pointer*, not what it points to. That leads to two pointers pointing to the same memory. Now think when one of the objects `delete` the pointer, what will happen with the pointer in the other object?

Comment: Thank you. I think I programmed Matlab for too long :-D.

Comment: Without copy-elision, your "the second" would be "copy/move-construction", not copy-construction. (Which means move-construction unless the class's move-constructor is not generated at all)